# What is the use of solvers that return approximately-feasible solutions?

Tags: convex-optimization

Common methods for solving convex programs return solutions that are only approximately-feasible solutions. Here is an example (from lecture notes by Nemirovski on interior-point methods for convex programming). Consider the following convex program:

[image]

Interior point methods return solutions satisfying the following, for any given $\epsilon>0$:

[image]

that is: the constraints represented by the functions $g_j$ are not satisfied exactly - they are satisfied only approximately (up to $\epsilon$).

In some cases, approxiamtely-feasible solutions may be possible. For example, if the constraints represent budget, we may be able to get a slightly larger budget than planned. But sometimes it is impossible. For exmaple, if we look for a probability distribution, then the sum of probabilities must be 1 - we cannot have a distribution with sum of probabilities larger than 1.

In all papers that use convex programming, I have never seen any mention of this "approximately-feasible" issue. This is quite puzzling: how can we be sure that a solution, that is only approximately-feasible, is useful in practice?

Comment: $\epsilon$ is quite small in practice

Comment: Typically you're sacrificing accuracy for speed, and ofttimes it's easier to find the nearest feasible point relative to a good point than to find the optimal point.